# Are all terms of type forall a. a operationally bottom?

Tags: computability, type-theory

Is there a proof that all terms of type $\forall{a}. a$ are operationally $\bot$, in a non-weakly-normalising version of System F?

If you ask a free theorem calculator [such as this one](http://free-theorems.nomeata.de/?) for the free theorem of $\forall{a}. a$ (written just $a$, as the tool adds implicit $\forall$s for each free type variable), you get the rather unhelpful

```
forall t1,t2 in TYPES, R in REL(t1,t2). (f_{t1}, f_{t2}) in R
```

Which seems to me only to imply that instantiations of $f$ at any two types are related by any relation.

Does this imply that $f$ must be a looping term?

Answer (score 1):

Sure, just take `R` to be $\{(\bot,\bot)\}$, the relation which only relates bottoms.

This is a strict continuous relation, so it satisfies the requirements of the free theorem you linked to.